# Why is bundler requiring an extremely old version of a gem when version not specified?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a Gemfile that looks like this:

```
gem 'google-api-client', :require => 'google/api_client'
gem 'my_baseimage', '0.0.3', :git => 'https://github.com/xxx/BaseImage.git'
```

I have a base gem that requires a bunch of common gems across projects.

However, when I run `bundle install`, I see errors like this:

```
  In Gemfile:
    activerecord (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activemodel (= 4.1.11) ruby depends on
        activesupport (= 4.1.11) ruby

    activerecord (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activemodel (= 4.1.11) ruby depends on
        activesupport (= 4.1.11) ruby

    google-api-client (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activesupport (~> 3.2) ruby
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    rack-contrib (= 1.1.0) ruby depends on
      rack (>= 0.9.1) ruby

    sinatra (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rack (~> 1.4) ruby

    google-api-client (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rack (= 1.2.0) ruby

    rack (>= 0) ruby
```

`google-api-client` hasn't required rack 1.2 since, like, [version 0.1](https://rubygems.org/gems/google-api-client/versions/0.1.0), and moreover `my_baseimage` requires 0.7.1. When I run a `gem dependency -R`, I see this:

```
    google-api-client-0.7.1 (addressable (>= 2.3.2))
    google-api-client-0.7.1 (autoparse (>= 0.3.3))
    google-api-client-0.7.1 (extlib (>= 0.9.15))
    google-api-client-0.7.1 (faraday (>= 0.9.0))
Gem google-api-client-0.7.1
    google-api-client-0.7.1 (jwt (>= 0.1.5))
    google-api-client-0.7.1 (launchy (>= 2.1.1))
    google-api-client-0.7.1 (multi_json (>= 1.0.0))
    google-api-client-0.7.1 (rake (>= 0.9.0, development))
    google-api-client-0.7.1 (rake (>= 0.9.0, development))
    google-api-client-0.7.1 (retriable (>= 1.4))
    google-api-client-0.7.1 (rspec (>= 2.11.0, development))
    google-api-client-0.7.1 (signet (>= 0.5.0))
    google-api-client-0.7.1 (uuidtools (>= 2.1.0))
```

I was able to work around this issue by, in my Gemfile, specifying 0.7.1, as follows:

```
gem 'google-api-client', '0.7.1', :require => 'google/api_client'
gem 'my_baseimage', '0.0.3', :git => 'https://github.com/xxx/BaseImage.git'
```

However, I was hoping that in my project-specific gemfiles I would not have to specified gem versions, they'd just take them from `my_baseimage` as-is.

Can anyone suggest why it would appear that `bundle install` is defaulting to a very old version of `google-api-client` when the dependency graph specifies the one I want (0.7.1) and `my_baseimage` also specifies the one I want (0.7.1)?

Comment: Have you tried removing you Gemfile.lock and running `bundle` again?

Comment: I had tried this yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundler uses rubygems, which, when not given a specific version, defaults to the last version marked 'stable', which, if the tag isn't maintained, can mean even terribly deprecated builds.

Comment: Thanks for this insight! Can you tell me - is there a way for me to determine which version has been marked "stable"? For example, Google API client is at: https://rubygems.org/gems/google-api-client/versions, but I don't see any "stable" tags. I did not see any "stable" tags in the github repo as well. Is there a handy way to list the "stable" version of a gem with gem or bundler?